# Count occurence of value combinations in data table

Tags: r, data.table

This is what I am trying to achieve in the moste efficient way possible:
I have two dataframes (`data` and `combinations`). `combinations` contains certain combination of some of the variables from `data`. For example:

```
combinations:
age       size
50        178
35        180
37        168
```

In `data`, I have all my datasets with all kinds of variables, so:

```
data:
id     age     size     name     income      ...
...    ...     ...      ...      ...         ...
```

What I want to do know is the following: I want to go through each of the rows from `combinations` in order to check whether and how often that combination of variables has occured in `data`.

So the outcome should be something like:

```
age       size    count
50        178     10    # this combination occured 10 times in data
35        180     2
37        168     5
```

Unfortunately I can't seem to find a way to do this. I really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Please show few lines of each dataset and the expected output you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `table` with `merge`

```
 merge(as.data.frame(table(data[c('age', 'size')])), combinations)
 #  age size Freq
 #1  35  180    2
 #2  37  168    1
 #3  50  178    2
```

#### data

```
combinations <- structure(list(age = c(50L, 35L, 37L), 
size = c(178L, 180L, 168L
)), .Names = c("age", "size"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -3L))

data <- structure(list(id = 1:9, age = c(50L, 35L, 37L, 50L, 
51L, 35L, 
38L, 42L, 53L), size = c(178L, 180L, 168L, 178L, 125L, 180L, 
124L, 134L, 129L), name = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "B", "D", 
"E", "F"), income = c(20L, 25L, 30L, 20L, 33L, 25L, 43L, 29L, 
39L)), .Names = c("id", "age", "size", "name", "income"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```